# Import data into R and skip till keyword

Tags: r, input, skip

I have a gas chromatograph's output file as .txt with a varying header length. How can I read the data into R without manually selecting/deleting the header? The file looks as shown below. 
So far, I tried different things (grep etc.) to find the position of "[Chromatogram (Ch1)]" or "R.Time (min)    Intensity" in the file, then only start reading in from there. No success though. 
I'd be really grateful for some advice on how to do this and also on how to skip the last two lines.

Best regards, 
Madelyn

---

```
Header 
Header
...
(differing in length between files)
...
Header 
Header
[Chromatogram (Ch1)]
Interval(msec)  40
of Points   4500
Start Time(min) 0.000
End Time(min)   2.999
R.Time (min)    Intensity
0.00000 -320
0.00067 -320
0.00133 -320
0.00200 -320
0.00267 -320
0.00333 -321
0.00400 -321
0.00467 -321
...
2.99800 363
2.99867 362
2.99933 360
[Fraction Collection Report]
# of Fractions  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is that you first read in the file than filter out the headers using `grepl`. For example:

```
lines <- readLines(input.txt)
lengthOfHeaders <- max(which(sapply(lines, function(line) grepl("R.Time", line))) - 1)
input <- lines[-(1:lengthOfHeaders)]
```

Comment: Hi Psidom, thanks for the quick reply :) 
This does cut off the header, but also part of the data. I also get a warning saying 
"Warning message:
In 1:lengthOfHeaders :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used"

Comment: I modified the code. Not sure how you files actually look like. It is possible that you have multiple lines that contains "R.Time"?

Comment: I checked and I do have one other occurence. I tried to use several different keywords that are unique, but didn't manage to get it to work. Here's a sample file, if you'd like to have a look:
https://polybox.ethz.ch/index.php/s/4H7FD65ps0V1ZC3

Comment: There are three tables in your file. Do you want all of them or just the last one?

Comment: Just the last one ;)

Comment: Awesome. Accept the answer if you think it's helpful. :)